# I have a problem about using sqlite in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

i am getting randomized data to textviews when i click to button, but it is only works once, so how can i get changed data when i multi clicking?
thanks for any help
[You can see the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDwcj.png)

Comment: You will likely get down votes and/or a closed question by posting images of code. I would suggest editing your question after reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially replacing the linked image with code.

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue**

Your issue is that  you are are using the same cursor and therefore values throughout as the line `val cursor=db.rawquery` .... is not within the body of the listener.

**The Fix**

You need to refresh the cursor within the listener body. You can accomplish this by copying the line into the listener.

**Suggestions**

I would suggest making the body of the listener a function and that you simply call that function from the listener. You can then call the function to initially display the words.

**Working Example**

Here's an example that uses such a function (but rather than tabs uses TextViews) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: databasehelper
    lateinit var arabicword: TextView
    lateinit var englishword: TextView
    lateinit var frenchword: TextView
    lateinit var russianword: TextView
    lateinit var turkishword: TextView
    lateinit var ukranianword: TextView
    lateinit var changeword: Button
    lateinit var binding: MainActivity


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        arabicword = this.findViewById(R.id.arabic)
        englishword = this.findViewById(R.id.english)
        frenchword = this.findViewById(R.id.french)
        russianword = this.findViewById(R.id.russian)
        turkishword = this.findViewById(R.id.turkish)
        ukranianword = this.findViewById(R.id.ukranian)
        changeword = this.findViewById(R.id.changeword)
        binding = this

        db = databasehelper(applicationContext)
        setWords() // INITIAL DISPLAY
        /* Simplifeied Listener */
        changeword.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            setWords()
        })
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    fun setWords() {
        var cursor = db.writableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1",null)
        /* only need to move to the first as only 1 rows returned */
        /* also directly sets the Texts without intermediate ArrayList */
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            binding.arabicword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("arabicword")))
            binding.englishword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("englishword")))
            binding.frenchword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("frenchword")))
            binding.russianword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("russianword")))
            binding.turkishword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("turkishword")))
            binding.ukranianword.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ukranianword")))
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Ooops not changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```